# Using the fact that 6 is a primitive root modulo 109, compute the remainder when 424^2076 divided by 109

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Using the fact that 6 is a primitive root modulo 109, compute the remainder when  $424^{2076}$ is divided by 109.

I try with

ord_109 (6)=phi(109) =108

424 = 97mod 109

stuck here

Comment: The first step is : Reduce the base modulo $109$ and the exponent modulo $108$ to get $97^{24}$

Comment: still not understanding :(

Comment: Next we use $97^{24}\equiv 12^{24}$ modulo $109$. For $6^{24}$, we perhaps can use that $6$ is a primitive root, but I have no clue at the moment, how. Useful should be : $6^3\equiv -2$ modulo $109$.

Comment: This leads to $12^{24}\equiv 2^{24}\cdot 6^{24}=6^{72}\cdot 6^{24}\equiv 6^{96}$

Comment: Since the order of $6$ modulo $109$ is $108$, $6^{96}$ is the inverse of $6^{12}\equiv 2^4\equiv 16$. Finally, inverting $16$ modulo $109$, you get the final result $75$.

Comment: Perhaps not the easiest way, but manageable without a calculator.